# Spot light doesnt work for virtual reality in unity Urp

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, virtual, light, oculus

My point lights renders in unity but it wont render in the oculus headset. What could be the cause. I Could not find a solution online.

I am using URP

Answer (score 0):

Add more details if possible, are you using baked lighting, mixed, realtime? It might be your light per pixel setting.

Try to disable any other light in the scene and leave only the spotlight, increase the spotlight range and check if the spotlight works.

If it does, then it's your light per pixel/vertex count, you can edit it from your `Settings` folder, opening up the URP profile you're currently using, it's called `Per Object Limit`:

[image]

Do not go beyond 1 on the Quest and bake lights if they don't have to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "per vertex" have have 8 lights in the per object limit (with fantastic performance as well) but it may give you some strange results in some areas.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).